# How to cross reference macro generated bookmark

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word input form which pops up when the user creates a new document based on the template. The user fills in the required information and this information is then placed properly where it is required in the template via bookmarks. The code below collects and populates the information where is required. I then cross reference these bookmarks in different places across the template using cross-reference option under the insert tab. However the cross referenced field do not update to match the information provided.

Here is the code I am using to collect the information from the form and populate it in the bookmark:

```
Private Sub OK_Click()

    Dim UnitName As Range
    Set UnitName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("UnitName").Range
    UnitName.Text = Me.AgisanangUnitNameInput.Value

    Dim OrderNo As Range
    Set OrderNo = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("OrderNo").Range
    OrderNo.Text = Me.OrderNoInput.Value

    Dim ItemNo As Range
    Set ItemNo = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ItemNo").Range
    ItemNo.Text = Me.ItemNoInput.Value

    Dim Reference As Range
    Set Reference = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Reference").Range
    Reference.Text = Me.ReferenceInput.Value

    Dim DocumentNo As Range
    Set DocumentNo = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("DocumentNo").Range
    DocumentNo.Text = Me.DocumentNoInput.Value

    Dim RevisionNo As Range
    Set RevisionNo = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("RevisionNo").Range
    RevisionNo.Text = Me.RevisionNoInput.Value

    Dim ProjectName As Range
    Set ProjectName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ProjectName").Range
    ProjectName.Text = Me.ProjectNameInput.Value

    Dim PreparedFor As Range
    Set PreparedFor = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("PreparedFor").Range
    PreparedFor.Text = Me.PreparedForInput.Value

    Dim Classification As Range
    Set Classification = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Classification").Range
    Classification.Text = Me.ClassificationInput.Value

    Dim DocumentType As Range
    Set DocumentType = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("DocumentType").Range
    DocumentType.Text = Me.DocumentTypeInput.Value

    Dim TitleOfReport As Range
    Set TitleOfReport = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TitleOfReport").Range
    TitleOfReport.Text = Me.TitleOfReportInput.Value

    Me.Repaint
    ReportInputForm.Hide

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
Dim Rng As Range

For Each Rng In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With Rng
        If .Fields.Count Then .Fields.Update
    End With
Next Rng
```

You can limit this principle by excluding some StoryRanges (such as headers and footers) and/or update only selected types or even just individual fields.

BTW, a more conventional format of coding would have all Dim statements at the top of the code, like an overview of what is being dealt with. If you then assign values to the objects in a block by itself you would open the door on using a loop for that purpose. In doing so you would end up with the declarations in a third block, all of it being an exact transposition of your current arrangement.

Comment: I get the following error: Error! Reference source not found.

Comment: Haha. The intention was to help you do your own coding. If there are no fields to update in one of the StoryRanges an error will occur. I have modified the suggested snippet to show you how to avoid this kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I think, is that when you are adding the text you are unintentionally deleting the bookmark - hence the error. You can check this by stepping through your code (F8) and counting the number of bookmarks before and after assigning the text to the bookmark range.

By way of a pattern to use to 'preserve' the bookmark, you can do this:

```
Sub preserveBookMark()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim bmName As String

    bmName = "UnitName"
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bmName).Range

    rng.Text = Me.AgisanangUnitNameInput.Value  ' deletes the bookmark
    rng.Bookmarks.Add ("bmName")                ' re-add deleted bookmark

    activedocument.Fields.Update
End Sub
```